# Why are standard errors the same in lag-distributed model in R?

Tags: r, model

I am running a lag-distributed model ordinary least squares in which a set of units are all treated in the same year. I am including a 2 lags and 2 leads to see if there were any "anticipation" or "long-term" effects by generating the same treatment status in the previous and following years. However, when I run the model all of the standard errors are the same. For example:

```
set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100), id = sort(rep(1:10,10)), years = rep(2000:2009,10))

tr <- ifelse(data$years == 2005 & data$id %in% c(2,3,4,5,6),1,0)
lead.2003 <- ifelse(data$year == 2003 & data$id %in% c(2,3,4,5,6), 1, 0)
lead.2004 <- ifelse(data$year == 2004 & data$id %in% c(2,3,4,5,6), 1, 0)
lag.2006 <- ifelse(data$year == 2006 & data$id %in% c(2,3,4,5,6), 1, 0)
lag.2007 <- ifelse(data$year == 2007 & data$id %in% c(2,3,4,5,6), 1, 0)

data <- cbind(data, tr, lead.2003, lead.2004, lag.2006 , lag.2007)

summary(lm(y ~ tr + lead.2003 + lead.2004 + lag.2006 + lag.2007, data = data))
```

Any ideas why this is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your design matrix is orthogonal, the standard error for each estimated regression coefficient will be the same, and will be equal to the square root of (MSE/n) where MSE = mean square error and n = number of observations.